# Replace All Occurance of ${sentence} by 'message' in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have below string.

```
const msg='this is the ${sentence} to end all ${sentence}'
```

I want to replace all occurances of **${sentence}** by **'message**'.

When I am doing

```
var newMsg = msg.replace('${sentence}', 'message')
```

It gives output-

> this is the message to end all ${sentence}

But I want to replace all occurances of `${sentence}`. So I tried

```
var newMsg = msg.replace(/${sentence}/g, 'message')
```

And what if I want to replace all occurance of **dynamic String**.

```
var str = JSON.stringify(JsonData).toString();                 
  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(dummyData)) {    
       str = str.replace('${'+key+'}', value)
}
```

Here JsonData is the JSON file whoes values I want to replace with values from dummyData(which is an object)
Please suggest how can I achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @sagivbg I'm not ok with the duplicate as in that case it can be done by changing the quotes with ` to make it a [`template litteral`](https://beta.developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). making it not a replacement problem but a quoting problem

Comment: @jonatjano that is if the js engine supports it.

Comment: @epascarello bad habit of me to ignore IE but even [microsoft say you should not use it anymore](https://www.zdnet.com/article/microsoft-security-chief-ie-is-not-a-browser-so-stop-using-it-as-your-default/), also template literal is so largelly available that engine not supporting it already need babel and the like to do anything

Answer (score 2):

The [**replace()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method returns a new string with some or all matches of a pattern replaced by a replacement. The pattern can be a string or a RegExp, and the replacement can be a string or a function to be called for each match. If pattern is a string, only the first occurrence will be replaced.

You pattern is a plain string, not a regex pattern. So you should use regex pattern with global `(g)` flag.

```js
const msg='this is the ${sentence} to end all ${sentence}'
var newMsg = msg.replace(/\${sentence}/g, 'message')
console.log(newMsg)
```

**Update:**

As per your comment if you need to build the regex pattern dynamically then you can use `RegExp` class to build the pattern. Your code might be the following way:

```
var str = JSON.stringify(JsonData).toString();

for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(dummyData)) {
    let pattern = new RegExp(`/${key}/g`);
    str = str.replace(pattern, value);
    console.log(str);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help. But What if I want to replace all occurance of **dynamic String**.  
   var str = JSON.stringify(JsonData).toString();                 
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(dummyData)) {    
    str = str.replace('${'+key+'}', value)
    }

Comment: @JAYASHRISHINDE, please see the **update** section.

Answer (score 2):

A more general way with regex ,you can do like this

```js
const msg='this is the ${sentence} to end all ${sentence}'
let str=msg.replace(/\${(.*?)\}/g,"message");
console.log(str)


// you might use template literals 
let sentence="message";
const msg2=`this is the ${sentence} to end all ${sentence}`

console.log(msg2)
```

Comment: template litteral is the answer here, regex is only what op proposed because he didn't know template litteral I think